# Шрифт в Firefox не уменьшается

Tags: css, ubuntu, firefox, шрифты

Есть код меню

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Отображается под виндой нормально в хроме, опере и фф. Под убунтой в фф шрифт отображается размером минимум 14px. Firebug показывает что элементы и `li` и `a` наследуют `font-size: 12px;` В настройках содержимого в фф "шрифты и цвета" пробовал выставлять минимальные размеры шрифта — *9px*. Пробовал указать другие шрифты, все равно меньше *14px* не идёт.

Comment: Ubuntu, FF 52 не подтверждается, размер наследуется нормально

Comment: Покажите скриншот и настройки FF.